# How can one 'Go to definition' in Java and JavaScript using Emacs?

Tags: java, javascript, emacs, intellij-idea

I'm looking at jumping back into using Emacs as my primary editor.  The trick here is that I've never really done large project work with Emacs.  Up to this point I've used Visual Studio, but on my latest project build on Node (transpiling some CoffeeScript -- not something I can change) and Java, I'd like to make the full switch.  I am using IntelliJ/WebStorm at the moment, but if I had some of the features I find in those editors I'd be willing to make the move whole sale.  Surprisingly in WebStorm there is a **Go to Usage** and **Go to Declaration** feature for CoffeeScript (I'd imagine the same for pure JavaScript).

How do veterans of Emacs traverse code in a similar fashion, that is how do they normally **Go to Usage** or **Go to Declaration**?  It's likely different for Java than for JavaScript, but I'd like to know the differences and possible headaches of setting this up with Emacs.

Comment: For Java, I usually use [jdee](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) when I'm in emacs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm hardly an Emacs veteran, but I do have an emacs obsession.

For Java:

- semantic-mode doesn't seem to work in practice, but can theoretically jump-to-definition
- evil-mode (a bit overkill...) can jump to definitions just fine with evil-goto-definition

  - this works very well, and I'd even suggest porting it to a non-evil environment if possible
- imenu (this uses a regex engine to find definitions)

  - is already used as a fallback in semantic-ia-fast-jump
  - doesn't seem to work well on variables

For Javascript: Javascript has some very complicated scope styles, and, unfortunately, such styles are commonplace so regex based solutions can and will jump to the wrong definition at times.

- semantic-mode doesn't work at all
- evil-goto-definition (uses a regex engine) works great as always
- imenu (uses a regex engine)

  - doesn't seem to work well on variables
- [Tern](http://ternjs.net/) is a battery of (alien) semantic analysers which seems to integrate well with Emacs

In general, I'd really recommend using evil if you can, it's superb. If you think of evil as being, well, evil, then:

- For variables use semantic-ia for jumps in Java, and tern for jumps in JS
- For functions use imenu. It works well on both Java and JS.

And finally, here's some code that I use for almost all of my jumping. It lets you choose any function to jump to and uses imenu, so you can jump to things other than the current symbol-at-point.

```
(defun ido-goto-symbol (&optional symbol-list)
  "refresh imenu and jump to a place in the buffer using ido."
  (interactive)
  (unless (featurep 'imenu)
    (require 'imenu nil t))
  (cond
    ((not symbol-list)
      (let ((ido-mode ido-mode)
             (ido-enable-flex-matching
               (if (boundp 'ido-enable-flex-matching)
                 ido-enable-flex-matching t))
             name-and-pos symbol-names position)
        (unless ido-mode
          (ido-mode 1)
          (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t))
        (while (progn
                 (imenu--cleanup)
                 (setq imenu--index-alist nil)
                 (ido-goto-symbol (imenu--make-index-alist))
                 (setq selected-symbol
                   (ido-completing-read "symbol? " symbol-names))
                 (string= (first imenu--rescan-item) selected-symbol)))
        (unless (and (boundp 'mark-active) mark-active)
          (push-mark nil t nil))
        (setq position (rest (assoc selected-symbol name-and-pos)))
        (cond
          ((overlayp position)
            (goto-char (overlay-start position)))
          (t
            (goto-char position)))))
    ((listp symbol-list)
      (dolist (symbol symbol-list)
        (let (name position)
          (cond
            ((and (listp symbol) (imenu--subalist-p symbol))
              (ido-goto-symbol symbol))
            ((listp symbol)
              (setq name (first symbol))
              (setq position (rest symbol)))
            ((stringp symbol)
              (setq name symbol)
              (setq position
                (get-text-property 1 'org-imenu-marker symbol))))
          (unless (or (null position) (null name)
                    (string= (first imenu--rescan-item) name))
            (add-to-list 'symbol-names name)
            (add-to-list 'name-and-pos (cons name position))))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "m-=") 'ido-goto-symbol)
```

Comment: This is very interesting -- I'm a bit of an emacs enthusiast and wish there was more information out there for things like this. So Thanks!  Can you explain the 'evil' part of this?  Why is it 'evil'?  And Is this what you are referring to in general ( https://github.com/emacsmirror/evil)

After thinking about it for a sec is the 'evil' part just play on the 'go-to' aspects (or am I missing something?

Comment: [evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) is a Vim emulation layer which can emulate Vim's `gd` or "Goto Gefinition" command (line 2326 of evil-commands.el). Unfortunately, you'll enable vim emulation if you use it. It works very well, and since I love vim keybindings, I use it happily. However, many emacs users consider `evil` just that: a horrible compromise with the enemy :).

Comment: Also, you could use `evil-goto-definition` without evil (just don't enable `evil-mode` and you should be fine), I've just tested it. But you still have a massive library lying around doing practically nothing. If that fine with you then you have a solution!

Comment: It was on the tip of my tongue yesterday... `tern`  for JS.

Answer (score 0):

I run exuberant ctags on my project folder with the `-e` for [etags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html#Tags) options.  Once the TAGS file is loaded, you can use `M-.`, `M-,`, and `M-*` to navigate it.  The package [`etags-select`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EtagsSelect) is very helpful to select amongst multiple methods of the same name.

Other useful tools to find stuff are `helm`, specifically `helm-for-files` and `helm-find-files` (which can tap into the TAGS file to narrow file and keyword search), and `rgrep`.  I read [`wgrep`](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) is a good one too for search and replace but i haven't had a chance to play with it yet.

It's all slightly more manual (of course) than IntelliJ until you get the hang of it.  One thing though about switching, you'll still need a proper IDE to debug your code as i've yet to find a solution in that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using [malabar-mode](https://github.com/m0smith/malabar-mode) you can `jump-to-thing-at-point` using `C-c C-v C-y`.  This works for finding variable definitions and also finding the source for a class (as long as the source jar is downloaded).  Of course malabar-mode depends on Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best way to achieve proper jump to definition is to use an LSP plugin, either [lsp-mode](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/) or [eglot](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot) which should support the standard `M-.` key binding. A given LSP server for the language you're using supports emacs with static analysis / AST info